# How to create a release based on a two weeks old commit hash

Tags: github

I need to create a release based on a commit hash created two weeks ago.

I am not able to find the commit hash in the UI showen below:

[image]

How to create a release based on a two weeks old commit hash?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create locally a new branch based on your old commit

  ```
    git switch -c newBranch <oldCommit>
  ```
- push that branch and then select it in the UI you mention